# how to set htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

I have some problem in htaccess file actually i have my path in local server is
`http://localhost/mvc/`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

this htaccess file is working perfectly, but when i upload my project in server.the project has not run and the path of server is `http://fresha.in/mvc/`.

Comment: yes i have my file name is .htaccess. actually i don't need to do anything in local server.but i don't know how to enabled it in server.please

Comment: i am really sorry to say. but i already run my codeigniter framework on that server that is running perfectly. this is my own created mvc by following some video from youtube.